# How to properly install a python package within the code?

Tags: python

I need to install a package, matplotlib. Install it within the code. I am a beginner and have very little knowledge about python coding.

```
import subprocess
import sys

def install(matplotlib):
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", matplotlib])
```

Does that means. after the computer finish the code above, I can start using matplotlib commands?

But it don't seem like that, I stil get an error when:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The error:

```
No module named 'matplotlib'
```

How I can fix this? I know this is a very basic problem, but I need help. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could use pip's python module to achieve that.

```
import pip

def install(package):
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        pip.main(['install', package])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['install', package])
```

Comment: Yes - that, and safeguards for when things go wrong, and better yet - a check for matplotlib already being installed  is the way to go.

Comment: Getting `#AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'`

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute '_internal'`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh What pip version are you using?

Comment: `$ pip3.7 -V pip 19.0.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

Comment: Make sure to have pip3 installed if you are using python3

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: I have a Mac OSX. No `apt-get` available

Comment: Check this link for installation on mac 
https://evansdianga.com/install-pip-osx/

Comment: Are you sure you were running python3.7 while executing those commands ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192059/discussion-between-ahmed-ragab-and-devesh-kumar-singh).

Comment: while it certainly installed, matplotlib commands still dont work for me, not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the pip library:

**UPDATED**

```py
import pip
from pip import main
from pip._internal import main 

if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
    pip.main(['install', 'matplotlib'])
else:
    pip._internal.main(['install', 'matplotlib'])
```

Comment: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'

Comment: @Zing I have updated my answer :D I have this working in Python 3.7 :D